# bootstrap table not showing row border correctly

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

Trying to get to the bottom :-) of this, want to show a bottom border (for each row) in a bootstrap 3 table...

```
<table id="modalTable1" class="table table-condensed">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="success col-sm-3">ping</td>
      <td class="success col-sm-9">Ping test to host</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="success col-sm-3">http</td>
      <td class="success col-sm-9">http test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="success col-sm-3">ftp</td>
      <td class="success col-sm-9">ftpo test</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

That's my basic table, but I need to show it inside a bootstrap modal; I don't think the modal is causing the issue, but I've provided fiddles of the table with and without the modal.

What I tried so far:

I tried the following css, but neither had any impact:

```
tr.border_bottom td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}

td.border_bottom td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
```

...also this:

```
.table th, .table td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
```

[JSFiddle with CSS Styling](http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/tCgYC/10/)

As a last resort, I tried inline styling with `style="border: 1px solid black` on each `<td>`. That sort of worked, but oddly it shows a left and top border on the table, not the cells.

[JSFiddle with inline styling](http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/tCgYC/11/)

Here's a fiddle with just the table (no modal dialog)
[JSFiddle with just table](http://jsfiddle.net/SAFX/tCgYC/9/)

Not sure if this is a bootstrap `.table`, or css issue, but I'm too new to bootstrap to rule out the former

Comment: Your JSFiddles no longer show your issue. I see that the fiddles are referencing bootstrap 3.0.3 so it's not set to grab the [latest] version. I imagine, among many possibilities as a result of time passing, that a fix was provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First point, you can have it specified with basic bootstrap styling.

[Bordered table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-bordered)

Add .table-bordered for borders on all sides of the table and cells.

There seems to be another bug, i noticed that the class success is interfering from the background color .. removing the border.

Witch is caused by this declaration's position relative :

```
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative; /* <-- there's your money border deseapearrring ! */
}
```

**fix**

Adding position:static to your td.success seems to fix your issue.

```
td.success{position:static}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tCgYC/13/  or  http://jsfiddle.net/tCgYC/14/

I fugured it out after seeing http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes where the position:relative aren't added from the modal panel.

**[post edit]**

Seems related to this issue : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11623

Comment: I tested with firefox and it's working on my side. See second jsFiddle link in my answer to confirm.

Comment: confirmed, this is working and resolved the issue, ty.

Comment: I invite you to search over bootstrap gits, perhaps this issue is a real 'bug' and might deserve attention. Helping was a pleasure.

Comment: Oh, GitHub repository. There are menus on right side, 'issues' and 'pull-request' .. where people mention bugs and ask for fixes. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap  LOL  i just found this : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11623

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using !important whenever you're overriding BootStrap CSS. In this case, change:

```
tr.border_bottom td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}

td.border_bottom td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}
```

to:

```
tr, td.border_bottom td {
    border-bottom:1pt solid black !important;
}
```

Comment: DevAndy, give it a try over OP original jsFiddle, it's not this situation here. It's a positioning bug.